# Can't able to ssh through WiFi without Ethernet connected

Tags: ssh, boot, routing, ethernet, wlan

I recently bought a OrangePi Zero Single Board Computer. It works fine but i am facing an issue now, when i boot the Pi without Ethernet, router assigns the IP to the WiFi of the PI but i tried to ping it. It says connection time out and when i try to ssh in it, it doesn't connect.

But if i boot my pi with Ethernet connected, both interfaces eth0 and wlan0 works fine and i can even ssh using both wlan0 and eth0.

I even tried to disconnect the Ethernet in between and then tried to ping wlan0 interface, again the same problem persists. If i even connect the Ethernet again both interface works fine.

I am using nmtui network manager. Therefore, my /etc/network/interfaces file is empty

```
root@orangepizero:~# nano /etc/network/interfaces
# This file intentionally left blank
#
# All interfaces are handled by network-manager, use nmtui or nmcli on
# server/headless images or the "Network Manager" GUI on desktop images
```

Here is my ip routing table when eth0 and wlan0 is connected

```
root@orangepizero:~# ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0  proto static  metric 1024
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.120
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.130
```

Here is my sshd_config file... 
Note : I am listening on all IP Addresses.

```
root@orangepizero:/etc/ssh# nano sshd_config
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for 
RhostsRSAAuthentication
```

Here is the dmesg log ...

```
root@orangepizero:/home/mayank# dmesg


[    0.938512] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    0.958710] sunxi-ehci sunxi-ehci.1: SW USB2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    0.958785] sunxi-ehci sunxi-ehci.1: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    0.959878] sunxi-ehci sunxi-ehci.1: irq 104, io mem 0xf1c1a000
[    0.970075] sunxi-ehci sunxi-ehci.1: USB 0.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    0.971318] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.971364] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    0.992132] sunxi-ehci sunxi-ehci.2: SW USB2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    0.992193] sunxi-ehci sunxi-ehci.2: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    0.993010] sunxi-ehci sunxi-ehci.2: irq 106, io mem 0xf1c1b000
[    1.010068] sunxi-ehci sunxi-ehci.2: USB 0.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    1.011223] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.011278] hub 2-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    1.032097] sunxi-ehci sunxi-ehci.3: SW USB2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    1.032157] sunxi-ehci sunxi-ehci.3: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
[    1.032993] sunxi-ehci sunxi-ehci.3: irq 108, io mem 0xf1c1c000
[    1.050070] sunxi-ehci sunxi-ehci.3: USB 0.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    1.051154] hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.051205] hub 3-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    1.071966] sunxi-ehci sunxi-ehci.4: SW USB2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    1.072026] sunxi-ehci sunxi-ehci.4: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 4
[    1.072806] sunxi-ehci sunxi-ehci.4: irq 110, io mem 0xf1c1d000
[    1.090061] sunxi-ehci sunxi-ehci.4: USB 0.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    1.091178] hub 4-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.091226] hub 4-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    1.092013] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    1.112150] sunxi-ohci sunxi-ohci.1: SW USB2.0 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    1.112210] sunxi-ohci sunxi-ohci.1: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 5
[    1.112278] sunxi-ohci sunxi-ohci.1: irq 105, io mem 0xf1c1a400
[    1.175168] hub 5-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.175210] hub 5-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    1.195989] sunxi-ohci sunxi-ohci.2: SW USB2.0 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    1.196051] sunxi-ohci sunxi-ohci.2: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 6
[    1.196115] sunxi-ohci sunxi-ohci.2: irq 107, io mem 0xf1c1b400
[    1.255230] hub 6-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.255276] hub 6-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    1.276126] sunxi-ohci sunxi-ohci.3: SW USB2.0 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    1.276185] sunxi-ohci sunxi-ohci.3: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 7
[    1.276249] sunxi-ohci sunxi-ohci.3: irq 109, io mem 0xf1c1c400
[    1.335058] hub 7-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.335097] hub 7-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    1.355806] sunxi-ohci sunxi-ohci.4: SW USB2.0 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    1.355865] sunxi-ohci sunxi-ohci.4: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 8
[    1.355928] sunxi-ohci sunxi-ohci.4: irq 111, io mem 0xf1c1d400
[    1.415077] hub 8-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.415116] hub 8-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    1.415828] Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
[    1.416301] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    1.416324] USB Mass Storage support registered.
[    1.416445] usbcore: registered new interface driver ums-alauda
[    1.416567] usbcore: registered new interface driver ums-cypress
[    1.416690] usbcore: registered new interface driver ums-datafab
[    1.416788] usbcore: registered new interface driver ums_eneub6250
[    1.416886] usbcore: registered new interface driver ums-freecom
[    1.416991] usbcore: registered new interface driver ums-isd200
[    1.417090] usbcore: registered new interface driver ums-jumpshot
[    1.417192] usbcore: registered new interface driver ums-karma
[    1.417290] usbcore: registered new interface driver ums-onetouch
[    1.417420] usbcore: registered new interface driver ums-realtek
[    1.417525] usbcore: registered new interface driver ums-sddr09
[    1.417632] usbcore: registered new interface driver ums-sddr55
[    1.417740] usbcore: registered new interface driver ums-usbat
[    1.418184]  uinput result 0 , vmouse_init
[    1.419446] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    1.419915] sunxikbd_init failed.
[    1.419938] sunxikbd_init failed.
[    1.419961] ls_fetch_sysconfig_para: ls_unused.
[    1.419978] ltr_init: ls_fetch_sysconfig_para err.
[    1.420679] [RTC] WARNING: Rtc time will be wrong!!
[    1.420699] [RTC] WARNING: use *internal OSC* as clock source
[    1.421225] sunxi-rtc sunxi-rtc: rtc core: registered sunxi-rtc as rtc0
[    1.421333] i2c /dev entries driver
[    1.422157] sunxi cedar version 0.1
[    1.422246] [cedar]: install start!!!
[    1.422622] [cedar]: install end!!!
[    1.422990] sunxi_i2c_do_xfer()985 - [i2c0] incomplete xfer (status: 0x20, dev addr: 0x18)
[    1.423206] sunxi_i2c_do_xfer()985 - [i2c0] incomplete xfer (status: 0x20, dev addr: 0x19)
[    1.423410] sunxi_i2c_do_xfer()985 - [i2c0] incomplete xfer (status: 0x20, dev addr: 0x1a)
[    1.423613] sunxi_i2c_do_xfer()985 - [i2c0] incomplete xfer (status: 0x20, dev addr: 0x29)
[    1.423815] sunxi_i2c_do_xfer()985 - [i2c0] incomplete xfer (status: 0x20, dev addr: 0x2a)
[    1.424020] sunxi_i2c_do_xfer()985 - [i2c0] incomplete xfer (status: 0x20, dev addr: 0x2b)
[    1.424222] sunxi_i2c_do_xfer()985 - [i2c0] incomplete xfer (status: 0x20, dev addr: 0x4c)
[    1.424450] sunxi_i2c_do_xfer()985 - [i2c0] incomplete xfer (status: 0x20, dev addr: 0x4d)
[    1.424670] sunxi_i2c_do_xfer()985 - [i2c0] incomplete xfer (status: 0x20, dev addr: 0x4e)
[    1.424917] sunxi_i2c_do_xfer()985 - [i2c1] incomplete xfer (status: 0x20, dev addr: 0x18)
[    1.425155] sunxi_i2c_do_xfer()985 - [i2c1] incomplete xfer (status: 0x20, dev addr: 0x19)
[    1.425393] sunxi_i2c_do_xfer()985 - [i2c1] incomplete xfer (status: 0x20, dev addr: 0x1a)
[    1.425630] sunxi_i2c_do_xfer()985 - [i2c1] incomplete xfer (status: 0x20, dev addr: 0x29)
[    1.425868] sunxi_i2c_do_xfer()985 - [i2c1] incomplete xfer (status: 0x20, dev addr: 0x2a)
[    1.426107] sunxi_i2c_do_xfer()985 - [i2c1] incomplete xfer (status: 0x20, dev addr: 0x2b)
[    1.426344] sunxi_i2c_do_xfer()985 - [i2c1] incomplete xfer (status: 0x20, dev addr: 0x4c)
[    1.426581] sunxi_i2c_do_xfer()985 - [i2c1] incomplete xfer (status: 0x20, dev addr: 0x4d)
[    1.426818] sunxi_i2c_do_xfer()985 - [i2c1] incomplete xfer (status: 0x20, dev addr: 0x4e)
[    1.426849] sunxi_wdt_init_module: sunxi WatchDog Timer Driver v1.0
[    1.427189] sunxi_wdt_probe: devm_ioremap return wdt_reg 0xf1c20ca0, res->start 0x01c20ca0, res->end 0x01c20cbf
[    1.427511] sunxi_wdt_probe: initialized (g_timeout=16s, g_nowayout=0)
[    1.427538] wdt_enable, write reg 0xf1c20cb8 val 0x00000000
[    1.427560] timeout_to_interv, line 167
[    1.427577] interv_to_timeout, line 189
[    1.427597] wdt_set_tmout, write 0x000000b0 to mode reg 0xf1c20cb8, actual timeout 16 sec
[    1.428429] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.22.0-ioctl (2011-10-19) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
[    1.428829] calibrat: max_cpufreq 1008Mhz Type 1!
[    1.428855] [cpu_freq] ERR:get cpu extremity frequency from sysconfig failed, use max_freq
[    1.429484] [mmc]: SD/MMC/SDIO Host Controller Driver(v1.111 2015-4-13 15:24) Compiled in Feb 23 2017 at 19:53:48
[    1.429553] [mmc]: get mmc0's sdc_power is null!
[    1.429612] [mmc]: get mmc1's sdc_power is null!
[    1.429631] [mmc]: get mmc1's 2xmode ok, val = 1
[    1.429651] [mmc]: get mmc1's ddrmode ok, val = 1
[    1.429684] [mmc]: MMC host used card: 0x3, boot card: 0x0, io_card 2
[    1.434389] [mmc]: sdc0 power_supply is null
[    1.437189] no blue_led, ignore it!
[    1.437669] Registered led device: red_led
[    1.437903] Registered led device: green_led
[    1.437936] no led_0, ignore it!
[    1.437952] no led_1, ignore it!
[    1.437967] no led_2, ignore it!
[    1.437982] no led_3, ignore it!
[    1.437997] no led_4, ignore it!
[    1.438012] no led_5, ignore it!
[    1.438026] no led_6, ignore it!
[    1.438041] no led_7, ignore it!
[    1.439742] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    1.439767] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    1.448220] asoc: sndcodec <-> sunxi-codec mapping ok
[    1.450721] [DAUDIO]sunxi-daudio cannot find any using configuration for controllers, return directly!
[    1.451109] [I2S]snddaudio cannot find any using configuration for controllers, return directly!
[    1.451138] [DAUDIO0] driver not init,just return.
[    1.458288] asoc: sndhdmi <-> sunxi-hdmiaudio.0 mapping ok
[    1.461109] oprofile: using arm/armv7-ca7
[    1.461461] u32 classifier
[    1.461481]     Performance counters on
[    1.461497]     input device check on
[    1.461512]     Actions configured
[    1.461896] IPv4 over IPv4 tunneling driver
[    1.463190] TCP: bic registered
[    1.463213] TCP: cubic registered
[    1.463230] TCP: westwood registered
[    1.463246] TCP: highspeed registered
[    1.463262] TCP: hybla registered
[    1.463277] TCP: htcp registered
[    1.463293] TCP: vegas registered
[    1.463309] TCP: veno registered
[    1.463324] TCP: scalable registered
[    1.463340] TCP: lp registered
[    1.463356] TCP: yeah registered
[    1.463372] TCP: illinois registered
[    1.463387] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
[    1.463837] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    1.466221] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    1.466284] NET: Registered protocol family 15
[    1.466374] Registering the dns_resolver key type
[    1.467531] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 2 part 30 variant 7 rev 5
[    1.467576] ThumbEE CPU extension supported.
[    1.467619] Registering SWP/SWPB emulation handler
[    1.468734] registered taskstats version 1
[    1.470417] cmdline,disp=
[    1.470791] [DISP] disp_init_tv,line:539:screen 0 do not support TV TYPE!
[    1.470830] [DISP] bsp_disp_tv_register,line:990:'ptv is null
[    1.470853] tv registered!!
[    1.470980] [DISP] disp_device_attached_and_enable,line:159:attched ok, mgr1<-->device1, type=2, mode=11
[    1.480565] ths_fetch_sysconfig_para: type err  device_used = 1.
[    1.483260] CPU Budget:corekeeper enabled
[    1.483749] CPU Budget:Register notifier
[    1.483775] CPU Budget:register Success
[    1.483800] sunxi-budget-cooling sunxi-budget-cooling: Cooling device registered: thermal-budget-0
[    1.490595] [rf_pm]: Did not config module_power1 in sys_config
[    1.490623] [rf_pm]: Did not config module_power2 in sys_config
[    1.490645] [rf_pm]: Did not config module_power3 in sys_config
[    1.490666] [rf_pm]: mod has no chip_en gpio
[    1.490684] [rf_pm]: regulator on.
[    1.490717] [rf_pm]: set losc_out 32k out[wifi_pm]: set wl_reg_on 1 !
[    1.549430] mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address aaaa
[    1.550522] mmcblk0: mmc0:aaaa SS08G 7.40 GiB
[    1.553946]  mmcblk0: p1
[    1.554969] mmcblk mmc0:aaaa: Card claimed for testing.
[    1.554999] mmc0:aaaa: SS08G 7.40 GiB
[    1.591339] [wifi_pm]: get wifi_sdc_id failed
[    1.592912] [mmc]: sdc1 power_supply is null
[    1.648738] mmc1: new high speed SDIO card at address 0001
[    1.691419] [wifi_pm]: wifi gpio init is OK !!
[    1.691532] [rfkill]: init no bt used in configuration
[    1.691555] ALSA device list:
[    1.691571]   #0: audiocodec
[    1.691587]   #1: sndhdmi
[    1.693346] Freeing init memory: 332K
[    1.776600] systemd-udevd[96]: starting version 215
[    2.613445] Btrfs loaded
[    3.084545] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p1): mounted filesystem with writeback data mode. Opts: (null)
[    4.290630] systemd[1]: systemd 215 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +SYSVINIT +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +ACL +XZ -SECCOMP -APPARMOR)
[    4.291299] systemd[1]: Detected architecture 'arm'.
[    4.335894] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <orangepizero>.
[    4.766400] systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency job for unit display-manager.service, ignoring: Unit display-manager.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
[    4.771956] systemd[1]: Expecting device dev-ttyGS0.device...
[    4.790320] systemd[1]: Expecting device dev-ttyS0.device...
[    4.810269] systemd[1]: Starting Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[    4.810757] systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[    4.810903] systemd[1]: Starting Remote File Systems (Pre).
[    4.830253] systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems (Pre).
[    4.830450] systemd[1]: Starting Encrypted Volumes.
[    4.850252] systemd[1]: Reached target Encrypted Volumes.
[    4.850439] systemd[1]: Starting Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch.
[    4.850864] systemd[1]: Started Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch.
[    4.850987] systemd[1]: Starting Paths.
[    4.870256] systemd[1]: Reached target Paths.
[    4.870515] systemd[1]: Starting Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[    4.890269] systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[    4.890460] systemd[1]: Starting Root Slice.
[    4.910246] systemd[1]: Created slice Root Slice.
[    4.910384] systemd[1]: Starting /dev/initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[    4.930263] systemd[1]: Listening on /dev/initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[    4.930400] systemd[1]: Starting Delayed Shutdown Socket.
[    4.950245] systemd[1]: Listening on Delayed Shutdown Socket.
[    4.950379] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[    4.970251] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[    4.970392] systemd[1]: Starting User and Session Slice.
[    4.990253] systemd[1]: Created slice User and Session Slice.
[    4.990426] systemd[1]: Starting udev Control Socket.
[    5.010256] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
[    5.010419] systemd[1]: Starting udev Kernel Socket.
[    5.030245] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
[    5.030417] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Socket.
[    5.050253] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
[    5.050505] systemd[1]: Starting System Slice.
[    5.070262] systemd[1]: Created slice System Slice.
[    5.070580] systemd[1]: Starting Increase datagram queue length...
[    5.211363] systemd[1]: Starting Restore / save the current clock...
[    5.311898] systemd[1]: Starting Create list of required static device nodes for the current kernel...
[    5.411594] systemd[1]: Mounting POSIX Message Queue File System...
[    5.500987] systemd[1]: Starting udev Coldplug all Devices...
[    5.592076] systemd[1]: Mounting Debug File System...
[    5.701113] systemd[1]: Mounted Huge Pages File System.
[    5.707746] systemd[1]: Started Set Up Additional Binary Formats.
[    5.707959] systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Set keymap...
[    5.841077] systemd[1]: Starting system-serial\x2dgetty.slice.
[    5.860404] systemd[1]: Created slice system-serial\x2dgetty.slice.
[    5.860649] systemd[1]: Starting system-getty.slice.
[    5.880314] systemd[1]: Created slice system-getty.slice.
[    5.887902] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
[    5.981417] systemd[1]: Started File System Check on Root Device.
[    5.981693] systemd[1]: Starting Slices.
[    6.000630] systemd[1]: Reached target Slices.
[    6.020368] systemd[1]: Mounted Debug File System.
[    6.040517] systemd[1]: Mounted POSIX Message Queue File System.
[    6.101352] [XRADIO] Driver Label:L34M.01.08.0002  Feb 23 2017 19:54:01
    [    6.101470] [XRADIO] Allocated hw_priv @ d6e67240
    [    6.102300] [SBUS] XRadio Device:sdio clk=50000000
    [    6.102625] xradio wlan power on
    [    6.102656] gpio wl_reg_on set val 1, act val 1
    [    6.130373] systemd[1]: Started Increase datagram queue length.
    [    6.152709] gpio wl_reg_on set val 0, act val 0
    [    6.154738] gpio wl_reg_on set val 1, act val 1
    [    6.210296] systemd[1]: Started Restore / save the current clock.
    [    6.254812] [XRADIO] Detect SDIO card 1
    [    6.310257] systemd[1]: Started Create list of required static device nodes for the current kernel.
    [    6.470510] systemd[1]: Started LSB: Set keymap.
    [    6.590308] systemd[1]: Started udev Coldplug all Devices.
    [    6.596253] systemd[1]: Time has been changed
    [    6.597349] systemd[1]: Starting Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...
    [    6.601474] [XRADIO_ERR] xradio_load_firmware: can't read config register, err=-110.
    [    6.601501] [XRADIO_ERR] xradio_load_firmware failed(-110).
    [    6.731413] systemd[1]: Starting Syslog Socket.
    [    6.750529] systemd[1]: Listening on Syslog Socket.
    [    6.750859] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
    [    6.890437] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
    [    6.938024] xradio wlan power off
    [    6.938078] gpio wl_reg_on set val 0, act val 0
    [    6.988261] [XRADIO] Remove SDIO card 1
    [    6.988579] mmc1: card 0001 removed
    [    6.989029] [mmc]: sdc1 power_supply is null
    [    7.063734] ep_matches, wrn: endpoint already claimed, ep(0xc097afbc, 0xd6a30cc0, ep1in-bulk)
    [    7.063778] ep_matches, wrn: endpoint already claimed, ep(0xc097afbc, 0xd6a30cc0, ep1in-bulk)
    [    7.063807] ep_matches, wrn: endpoint already claimed, ep(0xc097b008, 0xd6a30cc0, ep1out-bulk)
    [    7.063830] gadget_is_softwinner_otg is not -int
    [    7.063846] gadget_is_softwinner_otg is not -int
    [    7.063880] g_serial gadget: Gadget Serial v2.4
    [    7.063913] g_serial gadget: g_serial ready
    [    7.074002] [XRADIO_ERR] xradio_host_dbg_init failed=2599
    [    7.074032] [XRADIO] Driver Label:L34M.01.08.0002  Feb 23 2017 19:54:01
    [    7.074150] [XRADIO] Allocated hw_priv @ d6e5d240
    [    7.074761] xradio wlan power on
    [    7.074798] gpio wl_reg_on set val 1, act val 1
    [    7.124840] gpio wl_reg_on set val 0, act val 0
    [    7.126865] gpio wl_reg_on set val 1, act val 1
    [    7.166700] systemd-udevd[172]: starting version 215
    [    7.226966] [XRADIO] Detect SDIO card 1
    [    7.228536] [mmc]: sdc1 power_supply is null
    [    7.279737] mmc1: new high speed SDIO card at address 0001
    [    7.280968] [SBUS] XRadio Device:sdio clk=50000000
    [    7.282400] [XRADIO] XRADIO_HW_REV 1.0 detected.
    [    7.449751] [XRADIO] Bootloader complete
    [    7.648793] [XRADIO] Firmware completed.
    [    7.652052] [WSM] Firmware Label:XR_C01.08.0043 Jun  6 2016 20:41:04
    [    7.667293] [XRADIO] Firmware Startup Done.
    [    7.669691] ieee80211 phy1: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
    [    7.747359] sunxi_i2c_do_xfer()985 - [i2c0] incomplete xfer (status: 0x20, dev addr: 0x77)
    [    7.747431] bmp085: probe of 0-0077 failed with error -70
    [    7.760504] sunxi_i2c_do_xfer()985 - [i2c0] incomplete xfer (status: 0x20, dev addr: 0x48)
    [    7.760844] sunxi_i2c_do_xfer()985 - [i2c0] incomplete xfer (status: 0x48, dev addr: 0x48)
    [    8.399751] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p1): re-mounted. Opts: commit=600,errors=remount-ro
    [    8.775241] Adding 131068k swap on /var/swap.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:131068k SS
    [   10.538125] systemd-journald[171]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
    [   12.991199] Registered IR keymap rc-empty
    [   12.992787] rc0: sunxi-ir as /devices/virtual/rc/rc0
    [   13.031684] IR RC5(x) protocol handler initialized
    [   13.158761] rc s_cir0: lirc_dev: driver ir-lirc-codec (sunxi-ir) registered at minor = 0
    [   13.269608] gmac0: probed
    [   13.270238] gmac0 gmac0: eth0: eth0: PHY ID 00441400 at 0 IRQ poll (gmac0-0:00)
    [   15.060372] [STA] !!!xradio_vif_setup: id=0, type=2, p2p=0
    [   15.102065] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
    [   15.270361] PHY: gmac0-0:00 - Link is Up - 100/Full
    [   16.581088] wlan0: authenticate with 60:e3:27:fe:c3:60
    [   16.581151] [STA_WRN] Freq 2437 (wsm ch: 6).
    [   16.620255] wlan0: send auth to 60:e3:27:fe:c3:60 (try 1/3)
    [   16.710994] wlan0: authenticated
    [   16.720147] wlan0: associate with 60:e3:27:fe:c3:60 (try 1/3)
    [   16.724399] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 60:e3:27:fe:c3:60 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
    [   16.725922] [AP_WRN] [STA] ASSOC HTCAP 11N 58
    [   16.727653] wlan0: associated
    [   16.727929] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
```

Update : i removed some initial part of dmesg log due to word limit in stack exchange

Answer (score 1):

Check your routing table when only wifi is connected. (If I got it correctly,  the above is with both, wired and wifi being connected). 
Does it route correctly then?